# Cypress form submit to same url

Tags: javascript, cypress, javascript-automation

I am testing a form submit with Cypress. My Form action is the same has the current page URL. Once I hit submit it downloads a file. I am facing two issues:

1. Since my form action URL is the same as the current page URL, after submitting it went on an infinite loop.

```
    cy.get(urSelector.UserActivityReportForm)
    .then(() => {
        util.clearAndSendKeys(urSelector.FromCalendar, urData.From)
        util.clearAndSendKeys(urSelector.ToCalendar, urData.To)
        util.clearAndSendKeys(
            urSelector.SearchByCategoryTxtBox,
            urData.Category
        )
        util.clickSearchButton()
    })
    .then(() => {
        cy.get(urSelector.DownloadUserReportForm).submit()
    })
```

[image]

2. How can I Validate the file download is completed?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to click a button submit, you can try to find the correct name with the Open Selector Playground,then:
cy.get('insert yours button').contains('text of yours button').click({force:true})